# Overriding __iadd__ in python for fractions

Tags: python, magic-methods

I am trying to override the `__iadd__` method in python with fractions, now this is what I did. Please could some one check to see if I did it right. I have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047021/overriding-in-python-iadd-method) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35512684/python-execute-a-string-code-for-fractions), but that's not what I want. It should be used from a `class` perspective.

My `__iadd__` code:

```
def __iadd__(self, other):
    """
    Implementation of the '+='
    augmented function
    :param other:
    :return:
    """       
    newnum = self.num * other.den + self.den * other.num
    newden = self.den * other.den

    v = Fraction(newnum, newden)

    return v
```

This is done in a `class Fraction`with this structure:

```
def gcd(m, n):
    while m % n != 0:
        oldm = m
        oldn = n

        m = oldn
        n = oldm % oldn
    return n


class Fraction:
    # initializing variables for class
    def __init__(self, top, bottom):

        # check if entered fraction is an integer
        if isinstance(top, int) and isinstance(bottom, int):
            # reduce the given fractions to lowest term
            common = gcd(top, bottom)

            self.num = abs(top) // common
            self.den = abs(bottom) // common
        else:
            raise "Please only integers are allowed"

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.num) + "/" + str(self.den)
```

This actually return the write value when done like this:

```
f1 = Fraction(1, 2)
f2 = Fraction(8, 10) 
f1 += f2
print(f1)
```

Also did it by calling an overridden `__add__` method:

```
def __iadd__(self, other):
    """
    Implementation of the '+='
    augmented function
    :param other:
    :return:
    """
    if other == 0:
        return self
    else:
        return self.__add__(other)
```

The overridden `__add__`:

```
def __add__(self, otherfraction):
    newnum = self.num * otherfraction.den + self.den *     otherfraction.num
    newden = self.den * otherfraction.den

    return Fraction(newnum, newden)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use `__iadd__` to increment in-place.
- Use `__add__` to increment and create a new instance.

So, you can change your code as follow.

```
def __iadd__(self, other):
    self.num = self.num * other.den + self.den * other.num
    self.den = self.den * other.den
    return self
```

See also this question: [implementing add and iadd for custom class in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20204230/implementing-add-and-iadd-for-custom-class-in-python)

Note that Python has a [Rational numbers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html) module. Check the source code… But `Fraction` objects are immutable, so `__iadd__` is not implemented.

Comment: Tried it doesn't return the right answer. From what I read [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20204230/implementing-add-and-iadd-for-custom-class-in-python) we can either return `self` or `not`

Comment: @udoyen I wrote a small Fraction class using the above `__iadd__` method and it does work. What do you mean by _it doesn't return the right answer_?

Comment: with that `code` and this `f1 = Fraction(1, 2), f2 = Fraction(8, 10), f1 += f2
print(f1)`. It returns `1/2` the fraction in `f1` rather than `13/10`.

Comment: @udoyen I used the numbers in your example (1/2, 8/10). The result is 26/20. See http://pythonfiddle.com/fractions/

Comment: My bad pschill, Laurent, I missed the variable `self.num` and `self.den`

Comment: I am implementing this in an assignment as a python student, so need the best possible application method, +1. Thanks Laurent and pschill